# mongodb connections don't close after query

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am using mongodb on typescript and my problem is that the connections don't close after querying.

I had the following approach in doing it:

```
import { Db, MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

let cachedConnection: { client: MongoClient; db: Db } | null = null;

export async function connectToDatabase(mongoUri?: string, database?: string) {
  if (!mongoUri) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
    );
  }

  if (!database) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please define the DATABASE environment variable inside .env.local'
    );
  }

  if (cachedConnection) return cachedConnection;

  cachedConnection = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then((client) => ({
    client,
    db: client.db(database),
  }));

  return cachedConnection!;
}
```

and I use it in my nodejs server by doing:

```
const { db } = await connectToDatabase(config.URI, DB_NAME);
const result = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).aggregate([MyPipelines])
```

I have the database on Atlas and if I go to the dashboard I see **a lot of connections not closed, and when it reaches 500 then the server need to be stopped** because it goes in timeout and closes it. They send me one email saying "You're nearing the maximum connections treshold"

In fact now I have all these connections active.

[image]

And on console I get these errors:

[image]

What do you think I did wrong? Is there a better way to handle mongoDB connection with typescript?

Comment: You should use a singleton pattern and share the same connection object through all your application. When you open a connection, actually mongo is managing internally a pool of connections. Don't forget to handle the shutdown of your app, closing the global connection pool. Take a look at graceful-shutdown pattern, because sometimes apps crash and you should caught all exceptions and close connections before exit.

Answer (score 0):

You should close all connections when your app closes completely.

```js
process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
    await cachedConnection.db.close();
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Where sould I this code? and what is the keyword "SIGINT"?

Comment: btw there doesn't exist method close() on cachedConnection.db